# Slow/bad performance on Chrome with large amount of html

Tags: google-chrome, image-processing, tinymce, base64

When testing all the browsers with TinyMCE 4, Chrome is horribly slow.
(I tried removing all the plugins from TinyMCE but it makes no difference.)

Chrome takes about 20-25 seconds to render some HTML in TinyMCE that contains a few large-ish (500kb) embedded base64 images.

Internet Explorer and Firefox take about 1 second and Edge is instant.
(Edge is pretty damn fast!)

All plugins have been disabled on Chrome.
I have looked at the timeline under F12 and nothing is holding it up. According to the F12 timeline, everything was processed in 800ms - Yet it still takes 20 seconds to show up?

The delay is only when TinyMCE contains embedded base64 images.

Has anyone experienced similar behavior?

**Update:**

I have noticed that even when I open large documents in Chrome, its loads a lot slower than the other browsers. You can actually watch as the scrolling bar gets smaller and smaller as Chrome loads the document.

In other browsers, such as Edge, the whole page is loaded instantly.

Comment: If you open a standard HTML file with this same content (without TinyMCE) is Chrome suddenly faster?  I would start with isolating if this is a TinyMCE in Chrome issue or a Chrome issue.

Comment: Chrome is slow even with the standard content.

Comment: The the issue would seem to be Chrome and not TinyMCE per se - perhaps  it would make sense to change the title of this and remove the TinyMCE tag as this is not an issue with the editor as much as its an issue with Chrome?

Comment: I am having a similar issue with Chrome and TinyMCE. I have 8 inline editors and the browser responds to scrolling after seconds.

Comment: Yes. This happens in the latest TinyMCE (v.5.0.3) as well. What I have realised was the issue happens when having an image/images with 6MBs or more. This can be reproduced in the latest Chrome (v75) and IE (v11.285). This works fine in Edge and Firefox (they take time to load. But pretty faster than Chrome or IE)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that a) Chrome tries to render the superlong data URI inside `<textarea>` as plain text before initializing TinyMCE editor and b) it became superslow in Chrome 49 which switched to a supposedly more correct complex text rendering. However even before that, a few megabyte data URI (linked in [crbug.com/945203](https://crbug.com/945203)) would take 20 seconds to open in Chrome 48 and older as well as in current Firefox.

So if your workflow allows, you should simplify the HTML inside the textarea and instead set it via direct DOM manipulation. Like removing src attributes from the images and instead setting them via `src` property in JS would make the initialization almost instantaneous:

```html
<textarea>
  <img id=img1 title="SampleJPGImage_5mbmb.jpg" src="" alt="" width="700" height="933">
</textarea>
```

```js
tinymce.init({
  selector: 'textarea',
  init_instance_callback(e) {
    e.contentDocument.getElementById('img1').src = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,............';
  },
});
```

Alternatively you can hide the textarea entirely via an inline `hidden` attribute  which should be set in the html itself so Chrome sees it while parsing the file:

```html
<textarea hidden>
  <img title="SampleJPGImage_5mbmb.jpg" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,...........">
</textarea>
```

Note, you may have to apply more workarounds as these solutions were confirmed to work only on the standard TinyMCE init as shown above - that is without the plethora of plugins that you load in your test case linked in crbug above.